# Java Maven openapi/swaggerui generate file script

Tags: java, maven, swagger, openapi

I have a project built in Java Springboot + Maven. I'm trying to provide an open api doc for internal use only, so it's not hosted publicly. It currently generates an openapi file upon build, but it's causing some issues in the pipelines. Is there a way to configure it to only generate a new file when I run a specific script?

I currently have version 1.4.8 of springdoc-openapi-ui.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do this specifying a [profile](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) in your `pom.xml`

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>generate-doc</id>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
    ...
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
```

Then you can run it with `mvn clean install -Pgenerate-doc` to generate your files.

Answer (score 0):

f you are using Maven, you can just set org.springdoc(I had the same error, so i changed from io.springfox to org.springdo) in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

You can use :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
        <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.32</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: That's what I'm already using, although a later version. I'm not using springfox at all, just springdoc.